# Ubuntu 16.04 wireless disabled without soft / hard block

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers

I am using a newly purchased Lenovo T470 with Realtrek wireless on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After [Jeremy31's advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921483/no-network-device-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04), I installed the driver with -

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi-next.git
cd rtlwifi-next
make
sudo make install
```

However, the wireless only works in the first few minutes after reboot. It is later on disabled somehow.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-generic DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:56:5a:2b:97:c9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8822be driverversion=4.10.0-041000-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ec100000-ec10ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 54:e1:ad:1f:de:57
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=137.189.40.206 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:ec200000-ec21ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:2b:37:e0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.43.55.224 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

I have checked that it is not blocked.

```
rfkill list
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Is there any suggestion I should look into? By the way I have PrivateInternetAccess installed, but killswitch is disabled.